# Does Russia still use a Snowtam to report normative brake friction?

Tags: commercial-aviation, pilots, cold-weather

Does Russia still use the normative (Russian) brake friction when reporting [Snowtams](http://www.baseops.de/snowtam.php) for their airports? What about former Soviet (CIS) countries?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Long story short, as best I can tell everywhere except Kazakhstan uses the ICAO SNOWTAM format. Kazakhstan uses two different Russian formats depending on what airport you're at, which is an interesting approach to say the least.

First, the Russian format is described [here](http://pilotnotes.wikispaces.com/Russia+and+the+CIS#OPERATIONS-Russian%20Friction%20Coefficient%20(FC)), it's a decimal value where less than 0.31 is "unreliable" and more than 0.41 is "good". In fact, there are two Russian values: the "raw" value as measured directly by a friction device, and the "normative" value that is derived from the raw one (although I couldn't find any explanation of how). I guess that the raw value is supposed to be the actual [coefficient of friction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Coefficient_of_friction).

The [ICAO format](http://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/publication/files/snowtam_harmonisation_guidelines_released_issue_v_2.0.pdf), on the other hand, is an integer value from 1 to 5.

(Incidentally, I'm aware that I'm blurring the distinction between *format* and *values* here, but since there is so little definite information on this topic available - at least in English - I don't think it matters much.)

The Russia and CIS AIP includes a [Snow Plan 2013-2014](http://www.caiga.ru/common/AirInter/validaip/aic/aic-2013-06_eng.pdf) that states:

> [...] friction coefficient will be distributed by means of SNOWTAM in
>   ICAO format (Annex 15)

That immediately suggests that Russia and the CIS now use the ICAO format, and considering the lack of any information about Russian format SNOWTAMs in the AIP or on the web in general, it seems very likely that the ICAO format is now the main or only one in use.

However, Kazakhstan appears to be an exception. There is a [permanent NOTAM](https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/PilotWeb/notamRetrievalByICAOAction.do?method=displayByICAOs&reportType=RAW&formatType=DOMESTIC&retrieveLocId=UAAA&actionType=notamRetrievalByICAOs) for Almaty airport (ICAO: UAAA) in Kazakhstan that includes this remark:

> K0706/13 NOTAMN Q) UAAA/QFBCS/IV/M/A/   /   /4321N07702E A) UAAA B)
>   1312010001 C) PERM E) AT ALMATY AERODROME THE INFORMATION ON RUNWAY
>   BRAKING ACTION IS TRANSMITTED BY ATIS AS FOLLOWS: IN ENGLISH-IN VALUES
>   OF ESTIMATED SURFACE FRICTION RELATIVE TO MEASURED ''SFT'' FRICTION
>   COEFFICIENTS. IN RUSSIAN-IN NUMERICAL VALUES OF NORMATIVE ''RUSSIAN''
>   FRICTION COEFFICIENTS.

There is a very similar NOTAM for Shymkent (ICAO: UAXX) that includes this almost-but-not-quite-the-same remark:

> K0707/13 NOTAMN Q) UAXX/QFBCS/IV/M/A/   / A) UACC UATT UAII B)
>   1312010001 C) PERM E) AT ALL AERODROMES EXCEPT ALMATY THE INFORMATION
>   ON RUNWAY BRAKING ACTION IS TRANSMITTED BY ATIS OR ATC AS FOLLOWS: IN
>   ENGLISH-IN VALUES OF ESTIMATED SURFACE FRICTION RELATIVE TO NORMATIVE
>   ''RUSSIAN'' FRICTION COEFFICIENTS. IN RUSSIAN-IN NUMERICAL VALUES OF
>   NORMATIVE ''RUSSIAN'' FRICTION COEFFICIENTS.

There is no similar NOTAM for any major Russian airport.

If I put all this information together, it appears that:

- Russia and the CIS now use the ICAO format for SNOWTAMs
- Almaty in Kazakhstan reports braking action in the 'raw' Russian format
- All other Kazakhstan airports report braking action in the 'normative' Russian format

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting. As of today (December 2019), the Russian format seems to be in effect at least in Karaganda, Kazakhstan, with the added surprise that „point three“ (0.3), as reported by Tower, was sold as equivalent to braking action „good“, which it wasn‘t.